# How to verify and traverse XML with JavaScript. Really no better way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I'm doing a simple `jQuery.get` call to api.facebook.com to retrieve the number of likes for a URL. The result is in XML (which is unexpected in itself, but not the point here). The response looks like this:

```xml
<links_getStats_response xmlns=​"http:​/​/​api.facebook.com/​1.0/​" xmlns:xsi=​"http:​/​/​www.w3.org/​2001/​XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation=​"http:​/​/​api.facebook.com/​1.0/​ http:​/​/​api.facebook.com/​1.0/​facebook.xsd" list=​"true">​
  <link_stat>​
    <url>​godfisk.no/fiskenasjonen​</url>​
    <normalized_url>​http://www.godfisk.no/fiskenasjonen​</normalized_url>​
    <share_count>​35​</share_count>​
    <like_count>​402​</like_count>​
    <comment_count>​10​</comment_count>​
    <total_count>​447​</total_count>​
    <click_count>​0​</click_count>​
    <comments_fbid>​676768902366174​</comments_fbid>​
    <commentsbox_count>​0​</commentsbox_count>​
  </link_stat>​
</links_getStats_response>​
```

To traverse this tree and get to the text content of the `<like_count>` element, I'm doing this:

```
data.firstChild.childNodes[1].childNodes[7].textContent;
```

This bring me back to the way XML was handled in AS3 prior to E4X. I cannot help but feel that this is pretty vulerable, so I decided it would be a good idea to validate the integrity of the returned data before accessing it. That leaves me with this Christmas tree compound if-statement:

```
if (data
    && data.childNodes.length > 0
    && data.firstChild.childNodes.length > 1
    && data.firstChild.childNodes[1].childNodes.length > 7
    && data.firstChild.childNodes[1].childNodes[7].textContent) {
  // OK, we're good, go ahead..
}
```

Really??

Comment: learn what the `Accept:` header is for in RESTful APIs

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A bit cheeky, but really the better option since I'm already using jQuery:

```
var numLikes = $('like_count', data).text();
```

Or if trying to avoid jQuery at all costs:

```
var numLikes = xml.querySelector('like_count').textContent;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is use XPath, so for example to get to like_count element in your example:

```
var elem = data.selectSingleNode('/links_getStats_response/link_stat/like_count'); // assign the element
var value = elem.nodeValue; // to get the element value
```

for more information on XPath, please see the following [link](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_examples.asp)

Comment: Thank you. However this solution seems IE specific, where data.evaluate would be the corresponding function for all other browsers. But these are my options you say?

Comment: w3schools examples seem to work just fine on chrome and firefox.  Just did the test.